# Inicializar una variable final HashSet en un constructor en Java

Tags: java

El problema que tengo es sencillo pero no se como solucionarlo. Cuando declaro una variable `HashSet` que tiene que ser `final`, y después intento inicializarla en el constructor, me da un error de compilación y no sé como inicializarla de otra forma que no se está:

```
private final HashSet<String> ejemplo = new HashSet<String>();
public Class(HashSet<String> ejemplo) {
           this.ejemplo = ejemplo; //está asignación me da error de compilación
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una variable `final` solo se puede inicializar una vez, y en tu caso lo estas haciendo dos veces:

- La primera en la definición
- La segunda en el constructor al asignarle otro valor

Para poder inicializarla en el constructor la tienes que definir sin inicializar de esta manera:

```
private final HashSet<String> ejemplo;
public Class(HashSet<String> ejemplo) {
       this.ejemplo = ejemplo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Es que cuando a una variable le asignamos la palabra reservada **final** la estamos convirtiendo en una constante, por tanto, solamente se le puede asignar un valor  una vez, para asignarle un valor dentro del constructor quita el primer valor cuando estas creando la variable.